# how to resubmit binary without reset the review queue

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, submission

Hi I have uploaded my app and it is waiting for review at the movement, i have found issues that i fixed after upload, now how can i reupload it without a reset? i can see reject binary button but that will trigger reset according to apple(Please note that if you reject a binary that is Waiting For Review or In Review, your review time will be reset and you will start over from the beginning once you submit a new binary. )

also how long does it take from waiting to review to review?

thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apple specifically says that submitting a new binary always bumps you to the back of the queue, period. Otherwise people would try to game the system by submitting apps a week ahead of when they think they'll be done, and planning to swap in the final binary just in time.

If you found the issue, Apple likely will too, and they don't approve apps that crash during review. That'll bump you to the back of the line too, so might as well re-submit now.

It's been my experience that Apple usually gets to new submissions between a week and two, and minor updates are sometimes approved in a couple of days.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to upload a new binary without going to the end of the review queue, AFAIK or can find in any Apple documentation.